# No elastic Scrolling in ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

On my Samsung Galaxy S, the `ListView` gets an elastic effect if over-scrolled. But I don't want this in my application. Can I disable this elastic scrolling?

Comment: @user683813: It would help if you would define what you think "elastic scrolling" is.

Comment: Which list view are you using? The default android listview or a custom one?

Comment: This may be because Samsung modified the internal listview code to have the elastic effect. In that case you cannot disable it.

Comment: You will have to use reflection on the ListView and find some function that might disable it

Comment: Which version of Android does it run. It comes with a 2.1 by default.

Comment: Are you talking about the fadingEdge property ?

Answer (score 10):

If by Elastic you mean the way the listview handles overscrolling by doing it similar to the Sense UI or the iPhone, then you may be interested in [setOverscrollMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode%28int%29), [setOverscrollHeader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), [setOverscrollFooter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29), and [onOverscroll](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29).  Good luck getting it resolved!

Comment: These methods are available in Android 2.3. What If the phone is still running 2.1(default)?

Comment: You may look into how those are implemented and do something similar with your own custom view that inherits from a list view.

Comment: He wants to disable the elastic scroll, not implement it. And you can disable it only if samsung has exposed a `disable` api or by overriding the  over scroll(if API level is 9 and above.)

Comment: Or you could reflection to investigate the private methods in his specific case.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable elastic effect if Samsung has exposed a `disable` API for it, or you can override the methods specified in Ty.S's answer if the Android version is 2.3 or later (API level 9 and above). Otherwise there is no way you can fiddle with Samsung Galaxy's ListView.

Answer (score -3):

With theme you can override backgrounds but not disable scroll effect:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```